# What was ancient Philosophy written on/with?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, plato, ancient-philosophy

What did ancient philosophers, like Plato, use to write their works on/with, physically? (Tree bark, animal skin, types of writing utensils, etc)

Comment: I am not certain, but I believe they mostly used papyrus.  This might be useful : http://www.skypoint.com/members/waltzmn/WritingMaterials.html

Comment: And vellum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vellum

Comment: See [Papyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_books#Papyrus) and [Parchment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_books#Parchment) (Vellum is the finest quality of parchment) for "books" in Greece and Rome.

Comment: Vellum was for the rich, nobles etc. I would guess for established works, not new works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody knows what Plato wrote on because no originals survive.

However, papyrus was the standard at the time of Plato. You can check out some examples [here](http://bodley30.bodley.ox.ac.uk:8180/luna/servlet/view/all/when/Before%20AD%2079?sort=Shelfmark,sort_order). Leather was also used for writing in his time, but parchment probably wasn't popular until at least couple hundred years later.

It's worth noting that parchment wasn't simply invented on a particular date. It was gradually developed in stages over a long period of time. Different treatments of animal skin were used for writing and had been for thousands of years before Plato. There's a good chance ancient Greeks, Plato included, had access to something like parchment.

Answer (score 5):

According to Quintilian (Inst. 8 6.64) and Diogenes Laertius (3.37), Plato probably first wrote on wax tablets, and then retranscribed them on papyrus.
The image of the wax tablet (Plato: Theaetetus, Timaeus. Aristotle:De Anima, Parva Naturalia) to illustrate the memory, the acquisition of knowledge or the nature of intellect is also a sign of this practice.