# How did the ideas of a poor slave like Epitectus spread before the printing press?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, stoicism

Was he literate?

Even if he was, how did his ideas spread during his own lifetime? Was word of mouth *that* contagious back then? Were people writing down his ideas on stone tablets and passing them around (or was paper already widely available by then)?

Comment: Stone tablets ? see this [post](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30722/what-was-ancient-philosophy-written-on-with) for hint on ancient philosophy "written supports".